# Disable cursor to jump to error location after compile in Texstudio

Tags: editor, latex

I am compiling a large document (more than 100 pages) in TexStudio 2.8.6 (macOS Mountainlion) and writing a lot of equations.

Every time I compile the cursor jumps to the first error location inside the editor window (I know where they are, and they are listed in the error list), which I don't want. This makes me scrolling up and down to reach to my original point of editing every time I compile which is pretty annoying.

Is there a way this action can be stopped in TexStudio? A solution would be a big help.

Thanks for reading this question.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but if anybody is looking for the answer, the option is available at:

Advanced Editor -> Special Options -> Go to error when displaying log

Comment: Thanks! I had missed it on first sight. Easy to miss because it is placed on the right above a long text field.

Answer (score 0):

Now the version is TeXstudio 4.5.2. It is located in [Options] --> [Adv. Editor] --> [Special options] panel --> [Go to error when displaying log].